# Popty Ping is not working

Tags: python

For my homework I need to make a popty ping application, if you don't know what this is then here is a brief summary:

In popty ping, there are 3 words you can say: 'pop', 'ping' and 'popty ping'. 'Pop' is when a number can be divided into 2. 'Ping' is when a number can be divided into 3, and finally, 'Popty Ping' is when a number can be divided into 2 and 3. Let's say that you get the number 4, it would be 'Pop' since it can be divided into 2. If the number were 6 it would be 'Popty Ping' since it can be divided into 2 and 3.

Here is my code:

!!UPDATED!! The `x` now increased!!! Could you now give me suggestions on how I can improve the code please? THANK YOU!!!

```
    def endValue():
    x = 1
    endValue = int(input("Please enter your end value: "))
    main(endValue, x)

def main(endValue, x):
        print(x)
        poptyPingChoice = input("Is this 'ping', 'pop', 'popty ping' or 'nothing'? ")
        if poptyPingChoice.lower() == "pop":
            pop(endValue, x)
        elif poptyPingChoice.lower() == "ping":
            ping(endValue, x)
        elif poptyPingChoice.lower() == "popty ping":
            poptyPing(endValue, x)
        elif poptyPingChoice.lower() == "nothing":
            nothing(endValue, x)

def pop(endValue, x):
    if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        return
    else:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print("Pop!")
        x = x + 1
    main(endValue, x)

def ping(endValue, x):
    if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        return
    else:
        if x % 3 == 0:
            print("Ping!")
        x = x + 1
    main(endValue, x)

def poptyPing(endValue, x):
    if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        print("Popty Ping!")
    x = x + 1
    (endValue, x)

def nothing(endValue, x):
    x = x + 1
    main(endValue, x)

endValue()
```

Basically, when I type 'nothing' for the number '1', it doesn't add a + 1 to the `x`. I'm sure there is an obvious answer to this but I also want to know how this can be improved to be more efficient because I just know that someone will cringe at this terrible code XD.

Thank you for your help and I appreciate your opinions and suggestions on how to improve this!

Comment: Your X Increments are local in scope only. It's modification inside of your functions doesn't propogate once they terminate.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it!! Now i'd like to know if I can improve my code somehow?

Comment: You can write `x = x + 1` as `x += 1`. Instead of calling `main(endValue, x)` recursively again and again think about using a Main Loop.